# retrieving exception details in local and host

Tags: asp.net, exception

I have a function that get's an exception (ex) and retrieves it's details and then saves them into DB .

```
        public static void NewLog(Exception ex, HowToLog option)
    {
        // retrive details of exception
        System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true);
        string PageName = trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1).GetFileName();
        PageName = PageName.Substring(PageName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
....
}
```

this works in local but on host when an error happens and this function tries to save it into DB an exception " object refrence not set to an object " on code below :

```
PageName = PageName.Substring(PageName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Comment: can be the pagename null, or the substring get a value that is not correct, eg not found the \\ symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like PageName was null..

Comment: Why is PageName null, then? You'd need to provide some code to show where it came from. How would you expect us to help if you show us literally nothing?

Comment: It's working locally most likely because you have the .pdb files so the runtime can look up the symbol and find the file name.  StackFrame.GetFileName's documentation says it will return null "if the file name cannot be determined."